# Eloquent, combine row columns in where statement

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

let's say I've got a database containing some films, with the date that they have first been released in a column and the number of months for which I should be showing them in the cinemas in another colum.

What I would like to do is get all the cinemas that are showing any film.
I'm trying to condense this in a single query, something like this

```
 Cinemas::whereHas('films', function($q){
    $q->where('date_created', '>=', \Carbon::now()->subMonths(showing_months)));
 })->get();
```

showing_months is the number of months for which the film is showing. 
Is there anyway to access that column in a similar why to which i "access" date_created?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it makes sense to add months to a date like you do it, but a calculation based on two columns and a passed parameter could look the following:

```
Cinemas::whereHas('films', function($q){
    $q->whereRaw('date_created >= (? + showing_months)', [Carbon::now()]);
})->get();
```

**Solution for the edited question:**

```
Cinemas::whereHas('films', function($q){
        $q->whereRaw('date_created >= DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL showing_months MONTH)', [Carbon::now()]);
    })->get();
```